# XCode: Scenekit, graph scene is not shown in editor

Tags: xcode, swift, scenekit

I have some trouble with scenekit. I create a new game progect with scenekit, and by default it has a ship.scn, but when I oppen it, I see "nothing" in editor !

[image: viewport]

I'm using virtual machine for working with next configuration: 
VMware® Workstation 12 Pro
12.1.0 build-3272444

OS X El Capitan (v 10.11.2)
Processor: 2 x 3,34 GHz Unknown
Memory 4.6 Gb
Grapics: Display 128 MB

My PC configuration:
Windows 8.1 Enterprise (x64)
Intel Core i7-4771
DDR3: 8gb
Video: Nvidia GTX 660

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about video driver issues of a virtualization software.

Comment: I have the same problem on Xcode 10 and 10.2 beta 4. downgraded to 9 solved the problem. apple suck

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. This is caused by the VMWare VM. As far as I have researched there is no way around it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12405627)

Comment: I have added the fact that there is no solution to this - to clarify that this is the answer to the question. Please undo the downvote, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is missing some details. "It doesn't work" is not enough to help you debug your issue.

Which OS version? Which computer model? What screen resolution? 
Which XCode version? Everything is easily accessible thru the "About This Mac" menu.

Example:

```
  Model Name:   MacBook Pro
  Model Identifier: MacBookPro10,2
  Processor Name:   Intel Core i7
  Processor Speed:  3 GHz
  Number of Processors: 1
  Total Number of Cores:    2
  L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
  L3 Cache: 4 MB
  Memory:   8 GB
  Boot ROM Version: MBP102.0106.B0A
Intel HD Graphics 4000:

  Chipset Model:    Intel HD Graphics 4000
  Type: GPU
  Bus:  Built-In
  VRAM (Dynamic, Max):  1536 MB
  Vendor:   Intel (0x8086)
  Device ID:    0x0166
  Revision ID:  0x0009

Displays:
Color LCD:
  Display Type: Retina LCD
  Resolution:   2880 x 1800 Retina
  Retina:   Yes
  Pixel Depth:  32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)
  Main Display: Yes
  Mirror:   Off
  Online:   Yes
  Built-In: Yes
```

I have XCode Version 7.2 (7C68)

and I can see the content of "ship.scn" in the editor (screenshot)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEGGB.jpg)

Comment: I'm using vetrual machine for working with next configuration: 
VMware® Workstation 12 Pro
12.1.0 build-3272444

OS X El Capitan (v 10.11.2)
Processor: 2 x 3,34 GHz Unknown
Memory 4.6 Gb
Grapics: Display 128 MB

My PC configuration:
Windows 8.1 Enterprise (x64)
Intel Core i7-4771
DDR3: 8gb
Video: Nvidia GTX 660

Comment: Have you check if you are using the latest NVIDIA drivers? There could some incompatibility issues too. SpriteKit handles all of the low-level work to submit drawing commands to OpenGL. Before trying anything, are you even able to run the app and see the ship rendered on the screen?

Comment: Yes, I can run this app and see the ship on the screen, i can rotate it and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The first time you open a scene in the SceneKit Editor, there will be no selection, and your editor window will be blank. This is shown in the top bar of your editor window. You'll see something like "art.scnassets > ship.scn > No selection". You need to make a selection before anything is visible. Click on "No selection" and you'll see a popup of available scene components.

Comment: I select ship, but nothing heppend... I also try to select other components, but nothing happend. At my screenshot, there is selected ship element, but nothing shows on screen..